# Get line count for all different file types in a repository

Tags: git, bash

How would I get the line count for all the different file types in my repository?  So for example, if my repository contained 3 file types:

- java
- xml
- (no file extension)

I want the output to be something like this:

```
java 150
xml 20
(no file extension) 30
```

I can run a command that will retrieve the line count for a specific file type (`git ls-files | grep "\.java$" | xargs cat | wc -l`), but assuming I don't know what all the file types are in my repository, how would I go about retrieving them all with their respective line counts?

Comment: Do you want to get the line counts for *historical* commits as well? Otherwise, this really shouldn't be tagged `git`; it should be tagged `bash`.

Comment: No, the current state of the working branch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is really a Bash question: *How to count the number of lines in a list of files grouped by filename extension?*

Here's a lazy way using `awk`:

```
git ls-files | xargs -n100 wc -l | awk -F ' +|\\.' \
    '/\./ { sumlines[$NF] += $2 }
     END { for (ext in sumlines) print ext, sumlines[ext] }'
```

The key points:

- `git ls-files` gives you the list of files in the repository.
- `xargs` takes the list of files from its standard input and runs `wc -l` on them

  - The `-n100` flag is to pass to `wc -l` maximum 100 files in a single call. `wc -l` will be called as many times as the number of files in the repository divided by 100.
- `awk` does the heavy lifting of summing and aggregating the number of lines per filename extension

  - `-F ' +|\\.'` specifies the field separator: spaces or a dot. The idea is that the output of `wc -l` contains lines starting with spaces, followed by the number of lines, followed by a space, and followed by the filename. By using this as the separator, the 2nd field will be the number of lines, and the last field will be the filename extension. This will be useful for counting and aggregating.
  - In `/\./ { sumlines[$NF] += $2 }`, `$NF` is the value of the last field, in this example the filename extension, and `$2` is the number of lines, as mentioned earlier. That is, we sum the number of lines per extension. The `/\./` filter excludes lines in the input that don't have a `.`. The main reason for this is to exclude the line with the total from the output of `wc -l`.
  - The `END` block prints the filename extensions and their total counts

It's lazy because it won't work with files that contain newline characters, and it doesn't count the lines in files with no extension.

Answer (score 7):

***Note***: After reconsidering this, I really think janos' is the correct answer to the question asked. As it really provides the **line count** and not the **file count**, like my solution.

---

Using janos' solution gave me the following error (I'm using it on a quite big project):

> xargs: wc: Argument list too long

So I came up with the following solution (maybe not most elegant, but does the trick even on big projects):

```
git ls-files | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | awk '{print $2,$1}' | head -10
```

This basically consists of the following steps (may be modified by your needs)

- list all files known to git by `git ls-files`
- use `awk` to get all the filetypes of the files
- `sort` them
- make them unique and get the occurrences count
- `sort` them reversed (filetype with most occurrences on top)
- print them using `awk` (`$1` = count, `$2` = filetype)
- strip the list to the top 10 using `head`

Comment: It works, but it will count empty lines and comments as well. Right?

Comment: Is there any way you can suggest to ignore those? I am trying CLOC but it doesn't support many file extensions in the repository.

Comment: I updated my answer to avoid the problem of "Argument list too long", and to fix other inaccuracies. In any case, our answers do different things. Mine produces the *count of the content of files* grouped by extension, yours produces the *count of files* grouped by extension. It's not clear to me which one the OP actually wanted, it could be either way.

Comment: Yes you're right. And actually, when reconsidering this, I think the OP actually wanted really the line, and not file count :-)